# Getting an internal error while executing code on IBM CPLEX

Tags: cplex, opl

[image]I am new to CPLEX. I wrote a few simple codes to solve some linear programming questions on optimization. It worked fine and I got the expected output (to make sure if there are no issues in installation ). I am trying to execute an existing code for CVRP. I am getting below error.

"internal error (Please notify IBM) CVRP        Unknown OPL Problem Marker"

Kindly let me know if you need any specific information regarding it.

Comment: Is that the entire error message? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Actually, I'm asking the opposite. It would help if we can see the code that is failing. Otherwise, we're just guessing what the problem might be. Can you provide a minimal example that will produce the error? Is there anything under the "Engine log" tab (if so, please show the text, not an image)?

Comment: I have attached the exact error message screen print in question. I will try to create a verifiable example.

Comment: thanks i got it . in engine log there is nothing , its blank !!

Comment: I was able to fix the issue, the issue was the part of the code which was fetching data from the local xls file, it was incorrect. However, when I increase the dataset , it to 16 hours to run to throw error message

 "Description Resource Path Location Type
Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX: CPLEX Error  1001: Out of memory.->. INSECVRP  Unknown OPL Problem Marker
"
i was able to run the  code on smaller dataset, do we need to do some settings ?

Comment: I’m glad you figured it out. Your follow up question is not related to the original question. You should start a new question.

Comment: By the way, it is entirely acceptable to answer your own question and accept it. Especially if you can provide more details, this could be very helpful to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a solution but a workaround, you may try if a similar error occurs for you. I got the above error when I was trying to fetch data from local xls file using below code

`SheetConnection my_sheet("largertestregion.xlsx");`
 `time from SheetRead(my_sheet,"time");`
 `demand from SheetRead(my_sheet,"demand");`

As my data set was small, and I defined all data in my .dat file instead of fetching it from local xls. The issue got resolved. However, I am yet not sure how the above code did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem can be solved in one of two ways:

1. Bring the files to the local file of the project
2. Adding the path when writing the code

For example:

```
SheetConnection my_sheet("D:\\Education\\largertestregion.xlsx");
```